# Accessing variable from code behind Master Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, variables, master-pages, public

**Please see the image below**

[image]

As you can see I have a master page `Design.master` and the code behind it that is called `Design.master.cs`.

I am simply trying to get my page to redirect to `dashboard.aspx` when the user is not logged it, but no matter what I try I can't get it do it.

I want to be able to access the value of the public variable `redirect`, which is set in the code behind and access it from the `Design.master` code.

So that I can check the variable and put the `Response.redirect()` code in the `Design.master` page.

Unless you know how to get the Redirect to work from the `Design.master.cs` code?

Please help :( It's driving me INSANE!

**Updated image**

[image: adas]

`Design.master` code:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" CodeBehind="~/Design.master.cs" AutoEventWireup="true" %>

<%

        Response.Redirect("default.aspx", true);

%>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <title>Portal</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css" />

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="portal_script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="main_wrapper">

        <div id="header_top_wrapper">
            <div id="header_top">
                <img src="images/design/logo_small.png" id="logo_top" />

                <a href="basket.aspx">
                    <div id="basket_top_link">
                        <div>Order Basket</div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="header_breadcrumb_wrapper">
            <div id="header_breadcrumb"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="content_wrapper">
            <div id="content">

                <div id="side_menu">

                    <div id="customer_info">

                        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="CustomerInfo" runat="server">

                        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

                    </div>

                    <a href="dashboard.aspx"><div class="side_menu_item">
                        <div class="item_title">View Orders</div>
                        <div class="item_description">View your outstanding orders</div>
                    </div></a>

                    <a href="search.aspx"><div class="side_menu_item">
                        <div class="item_title">Product Search</div>
                        <div class="item_description">Search products and view stock levels</div>
                    </div></a>

                    <a href="search.aspx"><div class="side_menu_item">
                        <div class="item_title">Outstanding Complaints</div>
                        <div class="item_description">View status of complaints</div>
                    </div></a>

                </div>

                <div id="content_left">

                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="Content" runat="server">

                    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="footer_wrapper">

            <div id="footer"><p></p></div>

        </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Design.master.cs code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Design : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{

    public bool redirect = false;

    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {

        // Get the users session
        SessionManager session = new SessionManager(HttpContext.Current);

        // I've tried it here, and it won't redirect
        // Response.Redirect("default.aspx");

        redirect = true;

    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // I've tried it here, and it won't redirect
        // Response.Redirect("default.aspx");
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your code is able to tell when a user is logged-in or not? If so, then Curt's answer will work and if it doesn't, may be your problem is in determining if users are logged in or not.

Comment: You are trying to redirect from `dashboard.aspx` to `default.aspx` using code in the master page. Question: Does your `dashboard.aspx` use a master page to begin with? Please post the page declaration from `dashboard.aspx`... And also (since I answered a previous question of yours) did you try to put the logic in Global.asax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do it in your `Page_Load` method from `Design.master.cs`:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
   if (result){
      Response.Redirect("....");
   }
}
```

This is much neater than having code breaks in your markup file, and that technique will only bite you back in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I've tried this and the page simply doesn't redirect.  It goes on to load the page that I didn't want the user to visit.   It's extremely puzzling...  It's as if it doesn't load the Response.Redirect().

Comment: @Coulton I would assume that `result` is simply returning `false`. Where are you setting this to true? I see no reference to this in your screenshot

Comment: Did you try to debug it? What are the values? Are the functions even called?

Comment: @Remy I have completely taken out the `LoggedIn` logic, and I'm simply trying to get the redirect to work, and it wont just when placed on it's own within the `Design.master.cs` code.

Comment: add `Inherits="Design"` to your `<%@ Master..` directive

Comment: I have added Inherit to my directive and it just says it can't find it.  I am loading page "dashboard.aspx" and rather than redirecting, it is loading the code within that page rather than redirecting.  I put a breakpoint in `design.master.cs` and it doesn't even get to the breakpoint.

Comment: @Coulton Are you sure the master page is being rendered? Try making a change to the markup somewhere, maybe change text `Order Basket` to `Foo Bar`. Does `Order Basket` still appear? If so I would suggest you haven't correctly linked to the master page. Try posting your code from your markup file (aspx) if youre still having issues

Comment: I thought that putting it in `OnInit()` should cause that code to be loaded before the page loads?

Comment: It seems that the OnInit of the MasterPage was not being called.  I have created the 'OnInit()' override on the page that I want and now it redirects.  Can I put the OnInit() on the masterpage, or does it have to be on the individual pages?

Comment: @Coulton You can put it in the MasterPage. Here is a list of the order of page life cycle events, this should help you http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/archive/2009/03/08/asp-net-page-events-lifecycle.aspx

Answer (score 1):

`AutoEventWireUp` is set to false by default.  Looking at your declaration, this is why the master page methods are not wiring up.  Change the declaration to

`<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"`

Then you can add something like

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            if(!loggedIn)
                 Response.Redirect("login.aspx", false);
          //...
        }
```

Comment: I Brian please check out http://i.stack.imgur.com/LaN3G.png to see all of the places that I've tried to put the `Redirect`.  I have now put the `AutoEventWireup` to true as suggested.

Comment: Even if I put `Response.Redirect("default.aspx", true);` in to `Design.master` without any `LoggedIn` logic, it still doesn't redirect when I load the page.

Comment: @Coulton - Add a breakpoint to ensure the breakpoint is being hit.  Second, check the breakpoint is only hit once, no infinite loop of redirects.

Answer (score 0):

For your actual code use:

```
Response.Redirect("Page.aspx",True);
```

Having the true in your redirect usually fixes those obscure times when it otherwise doesn't work.